# Combine Solr Facets to one

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I am looking for a solution to combine solr facets on certain querys.
Let's assume i have a field color in which I want combine certain colors for a meta-filter called "pastel colors"

```
pastel colors (20)

 - mint green  (5)
 - sun flower  (8)
 - carrot      (2)
 - concrete    (1)
 - amnethyst   (4)
```

Users should be able to get facet counts also after a filter is selected, to show some filters like this:

```
pastel colors (20)

 - mint green  (+5)
 - sun flower  (+8)
 - carrot      (x)
 - concrete    (+1)
 - amnethyst   (+4)
```

I've seen that query faceting could work, but is there another solution?

Comment: You could get this to work in Solr via Pivoting: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/faceting.html#pivot-decision-tree-faceting

Comment: Be aware that if a product can belong to multiple colors, you can't assume that adding the facet filter will increase the number of documents by the same amount as returned by the facet. For efficiency you should really try to build the combined facets when indexing instead of when querying, as it'll allow Solr to look up the count of a single value instead of issuing queries for each derived value.

Comment: @HectorCorrea: Thanks a lot. Worked out nicely.
Acutally I can't index everything, since I have very special requirements for thousands of different request, what would bloat the index.